# Is there a variant of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm where the acceptance probabiltiy can depend on all states generated so far?

Tags: probability, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

I wasn't able to find anything on google, but is there a variant of the Metroplis-Hastings algorithm where the acceptance probability (**not** the proposal kernel) in the $i$th iteration might depend on the stats $X_0,\ldots,X_{i-1}$ generated so far?

I guess the problem is that the resulting process is *not* a time-homogeneous Markov chain anymore. However, it might still obey a law of large numbers ...

In order to motivate what I would like to do: I would like to generate a fixed amount of candidate proposals in each iteration (like in Multiple-Try Metropolis-Hastings) and choose among the candidates the proposal which has the largest distance to all of the already generated states. Would this still tend (in a suitable sense) to the target distribution?

**EDIT**: Let me try to formalize this: Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space;
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$ measurable with $$c:=\lambda p\in(0,\infty)$$ and $$\mu:=\frac{p\lambda}c;$$
- $k\in\mathbb N$;
- $q:E^k\times E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E^{\otimes k}\otimes\mathcal E$-measurable with $$c_x:=\lambda q(x,\;\cdot\;)\in(0,\infty)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E^k$$ and $$Q(x,\;\cdot\;):=\frac{q(x,\;\cdot\;)\lambda}{c_x}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E^k.$$

The idea would be that we are actually want to obtain a Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ with stationary distribution $\mu$ by running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$. By definition, $Q$ depends on the last $k$ states.

In order to actually apply this, we need to run the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm on $(E^k,\mathcal E^{\otimes k})$. I guess the target distribution should be $$\tilde \mu:=\tilde p\lambda^{\otimes k},$$ where $$\tilde p(x):=\prod_{i=1}^kp(x_i)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in E^k.$$ However, I Have no idea how I need to define the proposal kernel $\tilde Q$ on $(E^k,\mathcal E^{\otimes k})$, since it should intuitively be given by $$\tilde Q(x,B_1\times\cdots\times B_k)=\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\delta_{x_i}(B_i)Q(x_1,\ldots,x_k,B_k);$$ which doesn't work since this proposal kernel doesn't admit a density with respect to $\lambda^{\otimes k}$.

(maybe we should replace the domain of $q$ by $\bigcup_{i=1}^kE_i\times E$)

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you, I will check that out. I don't necessarily need a **Markov chain** Monte Carlo algorithm. If a suitable estimator can be formed out of the $X_1,\ldots,X_i$, that is all I need.

Comment: @Xi'an Is there a variant of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm where the proposal kernel can depend not only on the current state, but the past $k$ states (where $k$ is fixed apriori or maybe can even be adapted)? Something like what's being described here: https://www.academia.edu/16453972/Adaptive_proposal_distribution_for_random_walk_Metropolis_algorithm

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for your comment. How do the proposal kernel, acceptance function, etc. changed if we use an order $k$ Markov chain? Is there any reference considering that?

Comment: @Xi'an Please let me try to understand this: My definition is that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is a Markov chain of order $p\in\mathbb N$ iff $$X^{(p)}_n:=\left(X_n,\ldots,X_{n+p-1}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N_0$$ is a Markov chain. Now, you are considering $$Y_n:=\left(X_{pn},\ldots,X_{p(n+1)-1}\right)=X^{(p)}_{pn}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N_0.$$ I guess we easily see that if $\kappa_p$ is the transition kernel of $\left(X^{(p)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, then $\kappa_p^p$ is the transition kernel of $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, right?

Comment: @Xi'an Assuming everything above is correct: (a) Why do you consider $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ instead of $\left(X^{(p)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$? (b) I still don't see how you obtain a variant of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, where the generated chain has order $p$, from these considerations ... Is the generated chain $(E^p,\mathcal E^{\otimes p})$-valued? Do you simply choose a proposal kernel on $(E^p,\mathcal E^{\otimes p})$?

Comment: @Xi'an But that's simply the *definition* of $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ being a Markov chain of order $p$ as can be found in the [book of Douc et al.](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-97704-1): https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwRY.png.

Comment: Correct, moving by one index at a time in $X^{(p)}_n$ induces $k-1$ Dirac masses in the transition kernel. I still prefer the $(Y_n)_n$ representation as the transition kernel may then be continuous.

Comment: @Xi'an You've got a high reputation here, so I guess I simply don't understand your formulation. I've provided an answer by my own, which would be great if you could take a look at it. If I got everything correct, I will accept your answer, since it lead me into the right direction.

Comment: @Xi'an You are right, I made a stupid mistake. I think I've understood your attempt now: In each iteration, you sample a vector of size $k$. You first sample the first component $y_1$ from $Q((x_{t-k},\ldots,X_{t-1}),\;\cdot\;)$, then the second component $y_2$ from $Q((x_{t-k+1},\ldots,X_{t-1},y_1)\;\cdot\;)$ and so on ... This is interesting, but I think I still cannot achieve what I'm aiming for with this.

Comment: @Xi'an There is a very easy method (related to Poisson disk sampling, which is another easy method for the same purpose) to generate uniformly distributed samples with blue noise characteristics: https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/20/generating-blue-noise-sample-points-with-mitchells-best-candidate-algorithm/. I would like to incorporate this in MCMC. In order to simplify the matter, I've started to only consider a constant density (corresponding to a uniform distribution). Maybe the notion of blue noise characteristics needs to be suitable updated for a general importance function.

Comment: @Xi'an The definition of blue noise is somehow vague, but in [this paper](http://abdallagafar.com/publications/dyadic-nets/) (Section 5) a mathematical definition is given.

Answer (score 1):

If the dependence-on-the-past horizon, $k$, is fixed, a proposal based on the $k$ previous values of the sequence $(X_t)_t$ defines an order $k$ Markov chain, i.e.
$$\forall t\in\mathbb Z,\quad\mathbb P(X_t\in A|X_{t-1},\ldots,X_1)=\mathbb P(X_t\in A|X_{t-1},\ldots,X_{t-k})$$
An order $1$ Markov chain $(Y_t)_t$ is then made of the vector
$$\forall t\in\mathbb Z,\quad Y_t=(X_{kt+1},\ldots,X_{kt+k})$$
which is made of $k$ consecutive steps of the original Markov chain, since the components of $Y_t$ only depend on the components of $Y_{t-1}$ and of the components of $Y_t$ with lesser indices. This reformulation means that a regular (order $1$) Markov $(Y_t)_t$ can be constructed via a standard MCMC algorithm, provided a joint target distribution $\tilde\pi(y)$, $y\in\mathfrak X^k$,with all marginals equal to the original target $\pi(x)$, $x\in\mathfrak X$,  is defined. (For instance, it could be a copula.)

Practical implementation may however prove delicate / hard to calibrate though and I am not aware of a generic version (but [H. Tjemeland](https://www.ntnu.edu/employees/haakon.tjelmeland) may have proposed something similar in his multiproposal scheme).

As an illustration, consider a proposal at iteration $t$ with density $$q(z|x_{t-1},\ldots,x_{t-k})$$ and a proposed move from $Y_t$ to $Y_{t+1}$ using the proposals
$$\begin{align}
q(z|&x_{kt+k},\ldots,x_{kt+1})\\
&\vdots\\
q(z|&x_{k(t+1)+k-1},\ldots,x_{k(t+1)})
\end{align}$$
or
$$\tilde q(y_{t+1}|y_t)=\prod_{i=1}^n q(x_{k(t+1)+i-1}|x_{k(t+1)+i-2},\ldots,x_{kt+i})$$
Let $\tilde\pi(y)$, $y\in\mathfrak X^k$,with all marginals equal to the original target $\pi(x)$, $x\in\mathfrak X$, i.e.
$$\pi(x_i)=\int_{\mathfrak X^{k-1}} \tilde\pi(y)\,\text dy_{-i}$$
A valid Metropolis-Hastings scheme can then be based on the ratio
$$1\wedge\dfrac{\tilde q(y_{t}|y_{t+1})}{\tilde q(y_{t+1}|y_t)}
\times\dfrac{\tilde\pi(y_t)}{\tilde\pi(y_{t-1})}$$

Comment: Thank you for the edit. When you say "proposal with density $q(z|x_{t-1},\ldots,x_{t-k})$, your proposal is a single value (not a $k$-dimensional vector), right? And in your move from $Y_t$ to $Y_{t+1}$, $Y_t$ is the current state, right? I guess I simply don't understand your notation, but when you write "using the proposals \begin{align}
q(z|&x_{kt+k},\ldots,x_{kt+1})\\
&\vdots\\
q(z|&x_{k(t+1)+k-1},\ldots,x_{k(t+1)})
\end{align} I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Please write this differently: If $x_1,\ldots,x_i$ are the generated samples so far, then the proposal $Y$ should be an $E$-valued random variable taken from $Q((x_{i-k+1},\ldots,x_i),\;\cdot\;)$.